# Wordpress Woocommerce Robots.txt guide needed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need help regarding wordpress woocommerce robots txt.
My robots txt is fine.

I allowed google to [index](http://www.ontheway247.com/product-category/jewelry/) this.

```
domain.com/product-category/jewelry/
but the problem is google is indexing this 
domain.com/product-category/jewelry/?orderby=popularity
```

There are many ways to sort the product on every page and google is indexing all those.
i want google not to index this type of things.

```
/product-category/jewelry/?orderby=popularity
/product-category/jewelry/?orderby=rating
etc etc
```

but i want google to index this.

```
/product-category/jewelry/
/product-category
```

this is my current robots txt file.

```
User-agent:  *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /recommended/
Disallow: /comments/feed/
Disallow: /trackback/
Disallow: /index.php
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /cart/
Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /my-account/

User-agent: NinjaBot
Allow: /

User-agent: Mediapartners-Google*
Allow: /

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Allow: /wp-content/uploads/

User-agent: Adsbot-Google
Allow: /
 
 
User-agent: Googlebot-Mobile
Allow: /

sitemap: http://www.ontheway247.com/sitemap_index.xml
```

If anyone can help me solve this problem, that would be great appretiated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do this...

```
Disallow:  /*/?orderby=*
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress admin

then follow these

setting > permalink > select " post "  type permalink

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).